# Why would order of search terms affect solr query results?

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-9

If I search for `Authorname "Title of Work"` the records don't come up, but if I search for `"Title of Work" Authorname` then they do.

Why might this happen?

This is solr running on Coldfusion. The only change is the order of the terms.

#### Update

Sample coldfusion code. Note that in this example first one gets 2 matches while the second one gets 1. So it looks like this changes depending on the actual string searched, but it still means that changing the order of terms changes the number of records returned.

I could understand it changing the *order* of records returned, since changing the order would change the relevance of the results. But all 3 records should show up for either one. I'll see if I can find the solr logs and post them, that might help.

```
<cfset term1='"globalization of information"'>
<cfset term2='Reiter'>
<cfsearch name="ExampleOne" criteria='#term1# #term2#' collection="abstracts,fulltexts">
<cfoutput>#ExampleOne.recordcount#</cfoutput>
<cfsearch name="ExampleTwo" criteria='#term2# #term1#' collection="abstracts,fulltexts">
<cfoutput>#ExampleTwo.recordcount#</cfoutput>
<cfabort>
```

Output:

> 2 1

Comment: What's the exact URL being requested from solr?

Comment: Testing against my solr instance, I get identical results for `"intel ssd" fast` and `fast "intel ssd"`, using both the default and dismax query parsers.  So this seems to be an issue of how you're using solr, rather than anything inherent to solr itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the cfsearch tag. Perhaps somehow that affects it. I'll try doing a direct search to the solr server, see if I get the same result.

Comment: Your solr server is probably logging the queries it receives somewhere.  Figuring out what exactly CF is sending to solr will probably help identify the problem.

Comment: Changing the order of the terms should not change the relevance of the results in Solr either! However, I have sometimes noticed some inconsistent results when using distributed searching ("sharding") in Solr -- searching over more than one collection -- so maybe that is what is happening in your case. Have you tried querying a single collection at a time, and seeing if that changes your results? That is, if you query only one collection, do you still see differences when changing around the order of the terms?

Comment: @DavidFaber Okay! Looks like for some reason `term1 term2` matches in the fulltext index but *not* the abstract index, while `term2 term1` matches both.

Comment: @JordanReiter, wow! That makes no sense at all (not that I don't believe you - CF9's implementation of Solr strikes me as a bit rushed). I would recommend querying Solr directly using `<cfhttp>`. To query multiple collections you would use Solr's `shards` parameter.

Comment: @DavidFaber I may also just do two separate requests and merge the results. That way if one search already turns up plenty of results, then I can skip the other search.

Answer (score 0):

Just try giving search term in single quotes, I have tested in on CF 10 and it is working fine for me.
So Instead of:
cfset term1='"globalization of information"'

try this
cfset term1="'globalization of information'"

Comment: Also I'd rather not have to change the format of users' queries. Also, what do I do if they're searching for something like `"O'Reilly Publishers"` where the apostrophe is important?